# expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before

Tags: c

Why I can't declare this type?

```
typedef unsigned int8_t UINT8
```

Compiler error:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before UINT8
```

Comment: Why not use `uint8_t`?